# HowTo init boost::array with custom structure?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, struct, aggregate-initialization

I'm looking for a nice solution is how to initialize a static `boost::array` with a custom user structure and data. My example, what I'm expecting from `boost::array`, below:

```
 struct Foo
 {
      std::string a;
      std::string b;
 };
 static boost::array< Foo, 2 > foo =
 {
      { "111", "222" },
      { "333", "444" },
 };
```

But this code didn't work,

```
error C2078: too many initializers
```

What I'm missing?

Thnks!

Comment: This also applies to std::array. I'm leaving this comment here in the hope that search engines will show this question higher when googling for std::array problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the way brace elision works.  From N3485, 8.5.1.11:

> Braces can be elided in an *initializer-list* as follows.  If the *initializer-list* begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of *initializer-clauses* initializes the members of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more *initializer-clauses* than members.  If, however, the *initializer-list* for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough *initializer-clauses* from the list are taken to initialize the members of the subaggregate; any remaining *initializer-clauses* are left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is a member.

In other words, if the next thing is an initializer-list, we can assume no brace elision has occurred.   The braces are inserted at the innermost level, and so while we would like the following

```
{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}  -> {{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}}
```

we instead get

```
{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}} -> {{{"a", "b"}}, {"c", "d"}}
```

Now as to why we can elide even more braces and write `{"a", "b", "c", "d"}`: once we hit the `"a"`, we know that brace elision has happened, as we expect the array member to be initialised with an initializer-list.  We thus start consuming as many initializer-clauses as necessary to initialize the member array.  Again, we hit the `"a"` instead of an initializer-list, and so we start consuming as many initializer-clauses as necessary to initialize the first `Foo`.  We repeat this for the second `Foo`, consume all clauses, and end up with

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d"} -> {{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}}
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an extra set of braces works for me.

```
 static boost::array< Foo, 2 > foo =
 {{
    { "111", "222" },
    { "333", "444" },
 }};
```

More as I figure out why. I think the key here is "brace elision" (thanks to jesyspa for pointing me there)

This also works:

```
 static boost::array< Foo, 2 > foo =
 {
    "111", "222",
    "333", "444",
 };
```